Two definitions of Ramsey number coincide
I encountered two definitions of Ramsey number.

$R(s,t)$ is defined as the smallest $N$ such that every blue red edge coloring of $K_N$, we either have a blue $K_s$ or a red $K_t$.
$R(s,t)$ is defined as the smallest $N$ such that all graphs of order $N$, contain a clique of order $s$, or an independent set of order $t$.

My question is how to prove they are equivalent.

We can identify simple graphs of order $N$ with (not necessarily proper) red/blue edge colourings of $K_N$ by thinking of one colour (say blue) as meaning "the edge is present" and the other as meaning "the edge is absent".
In more detail, if we are given $K_N$ (say with vertex set $V$) with its edges coloured red and blue, then form the graph $G = (V, E)$ $uv \in E$ if and only if the colour of $uv$ in $K_N$ is blue.  Notice that every simple graph of order $N$ can be obtained this way from some red/blue edge colouring of $K_N$.  Going the other way, if we start with $G = (V, E)$, we can obtain an edge colouring of $K_N$ by setting the colour of $uv$ to be blue if and only if $uv \in E$.  Again, notice that every red/blue edge colouring of $K_N$ can be obtained in this way from some $G$.
In either direction, notice that a blue $K_s$ in $K_N$ corresponds exactly to a clique of size $s$ in $G$, while a red $K_t$ in $K_N$ corresponds to an independent set of size $t$ in $G$.
